# Easiest way to modify value passed to inline class constructor

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to use inline classes in Kotlin to create a class inlining the String class, such that if I have an instance of my class that it will always be true for the contained string that s == s.trim().

I was initially expecting there to be a straightforward way to do this, like perhaps:

```kotlin
@JvmInline
value class Trimmed private constructor(val str: String) : {
    constructor(s : String) : super(s.trim())
}
```

but that doesn't work, and neither do the other direct approaches I considered ("`this(s.trim())`", etc.).

This problem has turned out to be surprisingly tricky:

1. Kotlin seems to provide no easy way to have the primary constructor filter or modify the data that is passed to the constructor of the contained String object.
2. Even if I make the primary constructor private, I can't declare another constructor with the same signature (taking a single String as a parameter).
3. If this were a normal (non-inlined) class, I could just set the value after superclass class construction (e.g. "`init { str = str.trim() }`", but since it's an inline class, I can't do that. ("`this=this.trim()`" doesn't work either, and String objects themselves are immutable so I can't change the contents of 'str'.)
4. I tried making the class constructor private and creating a factory function in the same file with the same name as the class, but then I couldn't call the class constructor from within the factory function due to access restrictions.
5. I then tried making the factory function within the class's companion object, but then Kotlin tried to make that function call itself recursively instead of calling the class's constructor. I wasn't able to find a way to syntactially disambiguate this. I managed to work around this by creating a file-private typealias to give another name for the class so I could call the constructor from within the factory function. (Annoyingly, I couldn't declare the typealias in the companion object next to the factory function: I had to declare it outside.)

This worked, but seemed ugly:

```kotlin
typealias Trimmed2 = Trimmed
@JvmInline
value class Trimmed private constructor(val str: String) {
    init { assert(str == str.trim()) }
    companion object {
        // Kotlin won't let me put the typealias here. :-(
        fun Trimmed(s: String): Trimmed = Trimmed2(s.trim()) // Don't want recursion here!
    }
}
```

4. Another working solution is here, using a private constructor with a dummy argument. Of course Kotlin complained that the dummy argument was unused and so I had to put in a big (why is it so big?) annotation suppressing the warning, which is, again, ugly:

```kotlin
@JvmInline
value class Trimmed private constructor(val str: String) {
    private constructor (untrimmed: String, @Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") dummy: Unit) : this(untrimmed.trim())
    init { assert(str == str.trim()) }
    companion object {
        fun Trimmed(s: String): Trimmed = Trimmed(s, Unit)
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler, cleaner way to do this? For instance, a syntactic way to clarify to Kotlin that the companion function is trying to call the class constructor and not itself and so avoid the need for a dummy parameter?

Goals:

1. Code to construct instances of the class from outside this file should look like constructing an instance of a normal class: '`Trimmed("abc")`', not using some factory function with a different name (e.g. "`of`" or "`trimmedOf`") or other alternate syntax.
2. It should be impossible to construct the object containing an untrimmed string. Outside code, and the Trimmed class itself, should be able to trust that if a Trimmed instance exists, that its contained `str` will be a trimmed string.

Comment: Would an extension function on String object fit your need ? Because if you create a companion object with a function : `fun String.trimmed() = Trimmed(trim())`, you could use it like : `"  Hello".trimmed()`, which would return back `Trimmed(str="Hello")` object.

Comment: I think you are misusing value classes. Their purpose is not to "have the primary constructor filter or modify the data that is passed to the constructor of the contained String object" as your first point says. They are simple wrapper types that are inlined to their wrapped types. `val foo = SomeValueClass("foo")` is inlined to just `val foo = "foo"`. If you want it to be inlined to `val foo = "foo".trimmed()`, then you need a (inline) *function*, which is what you have written in both your successful attempts.

Comment: Therefore, I don't think there is much reason to get obsessed with the constructor syntax `Trimmed("foo")`. The code is just as readable (and arguably makes more sense, considering the above), if you make the call site look more like a (extension) function.

Comment: @amanin As I mentioned in the problem description, I want to make this object appear to users just like any other object. The fact that it is (currently) implemented as a value class is just an internal optimization and should not be visible to its users, who don't care how it's implemented: they just want to use it. Also my real object (not the example for this SO question) does not just represent "a trimmed string": It is a node ID that is very specific to my application, with a complex API, and would not therefore make sense as an extension on a general-purpose class like String.

Comment: @Sweeper I understand what value classes are. They have no problem providing complex initialization logic in cases where secondary constructors take different parameters than the primary constructor and delegate to it as in my second example. The problem here is that the existence of the primary constructor prevents me from creating the secondary constructor I want to have which would modify its argument before delegating it to the primary constructor, because my new constructor would take the same parameters as the primary constructor, and Kotlin considers them to clash.

Comment: If the use of value classes were intended to be as simple as being "simple wrapper types that are inlined to their wrapped types", then there would be no reason for secondary constructors to be allowed at all. Complex initialization by secondary constructors is explicitly allowed: just not in the case where the signature of the secondary constructor would be the same as the primary one. Which is the problem I am trying to work around.